# Regex that captures the string "\s @ \s" and only that

Tags: regex, regex-group

So I am reading in a string and it is always split by x @ y, with x or y being its own string such as "John Doe" and "Jane Doe". My regex currently gets the string "John Doe " and " Jane Doe". I want the line to be split on the white space with the @ symbol. Does anyone know a regex for that?

Comment: try out for yourself here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Given this string: `john doe @ jane doe` you can use this regex `(.*)\s@\s(.*$)` and you will have `john doe` and `jane doe` as your two capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

the regex was this (\s\@\s). it worked